# Wait for a javascript script to finish before proceeding with webbrowser? [Captcha image + picturebox]

Tags: javascript, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've been working on trying to grab a captcha that appears after entering a comment on Youtube so I could put the image of the captcha into a picturebox so i could enter it through the webbrowser component.

I'm not sure if this is possible but is there an event out there/custom event that I could listen for and wait until the script that generates the captcha is finished so that the webbrowser can grab the elements of the captcha image to copy it to the picturebox?  Currently when a captcha comes up it doesn't see it in the elements so it won't grab it.

Is this possible?   How else would I grab the elements for the captcha image?

Comment: This should solve your problem
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618252/captcha-image-from-webbrowser-control-into-a-picturebox

Answer (score 0):

If Captcha have "ID" You can try GetElementsByID. Example:

```
TextBox1.Text = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CaptchaID").GetAttribute("src")
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - The Image does have an ID however I'm not able to grab the element by ID through the webbrowser control for some reason. The image gets generated through javascript and if I ever give the program a second or two to wait until the image is presented on the page, the webbrowser itself turns white except for a few letters stating - INLINE_CAPTCHA

Comment: I think I know this problem. This is what you will do: Find what is lenght to chaptcha (Example: thisiscodethisiscodecaptcha.pngcodecodethisiscode There is 20 to captcha)
Delete that part with IndexOf. Use Lastindexof for delete code after .png .

Comment: I'm unable to do this method due to not being able to pick up the source of the captcha after the button is clicked, this is where the issue lies :)